# Exception from Tracker recompute function: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am getting this error in console log

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at null.<anonymous> (http://104.236.39.101:3000/client/templates/Professor/professorLectureView.js?026ec69298583f9fdeecadcdf9f2899a402df744:48:41)
at http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:1821:18
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:3382:12)
at http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:1820:29
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:2105:12)
at viewAutorun (http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:1819:18)
at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/tracker.js?21f0f4306879f57e10ad3a97efe9ea521c5b5775:308:36)
at Tracker.Computation._recompute (http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/tracker.js?21f0f4306879f57e10ad3a97efe9ea521c5b5775:322:14)
at Tracker.flush (http://104.236.39.101:3000/packages/tracker.js?21f0f4306879f57e10ad3a97efe9ea521c5b5775:452:14)
```

I believe it's due to calling the array seriesData inside my this.autorun function

```
this.autorun(function(){

    feedbacks = Router.current().data();
    feedbacks = feedbacks.sort(function(a,b){return a.postedDate.getTime() - b.postedDate.getTime()});


    if(Session.get('timeBarChart')){
        *irrelavent code*
    }     
        seriesData = [[],[],[],[],[]];
        categoryData = [];
        var topicName = "";
        for(var i = 0, len = feedbacks.length; i < len; i++) {
            comVal = feedbacks[i].commentType;
            if(comVal == 0) {
                *irrelavent code*
            }
            else{
                seriesData[comVal-2][seriesData[0].length - 1]++;   <--------------this line
            }
    }
}
```

However I don't see why this would cause an issue especially since seriesData is initialized a few lines above. I think it might be caused by meteor update to 1.0 because it was still working when it was 0.9

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the property was null because of an index out of bounds on the array. It had nothing to do with autorun.